# Drawing Over Microsoft MFP(Media Foundation Platform)

Tags: c++, video, drawing, c++builder, mfp

I am using C++ for Video play and analysis software developer. In here i have a question. I want drawing line and more shape over MFP video. How  can i this?.I tried catch WM_PAINT message and drawing process but unsuccess. I upload two image to showing problem. I can draw line but since MFP disable, but MFP writes video to over my drawing when MFP enabled.
Thank You.
[Before MFP Video Playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhU5L.jpg)
[After MFP Video Playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7kd8.jpg)

EDIT:Drawing Code

```
void __fastcall TForm6::Ciz()
{
  PAINTSTRUCT ps;
  Panel2->Repaint();
  HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID,2,RGB(255,130,0));
  ResetDCW(dc,devMode);
  SelectObject(dc,hPen);
  BeginPaint(Panel2->Handle, &ps);
  MoveToEx(dc, Dot2->Left + 15, Dot2->Top + 15, NULL);
  LineTo(dc, Dot1->Left + 15, Dot1->Top + 15);
  EndPaint(Panel2->Handle, &ps);

  BeginPaint(Panel2->Handle, &ps);
  MoveToEx(dc, Dot3->Left + 15, Dot3->Top + 15, NULL);
  LineTo(dc, Dot2->Left + 15, Dot2->Top + 15);
  StrokePath(dc);
  EndPaint(Panel2->Handle, &ps);
}
```

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: Thanks tadman. You are right. I added part of drawing code. MFP plays video on my TPanel. I want drawing shape over that playing video in TPanel. I am using GDI/GDI+ API for drawing. Also i tried DirectX to drawing shape but result same.

Comment: Hmmm.. what is `MFP`? The `mfp` tag doesn't give any clue. So, is it perhaps `Macromedia Flash Player`? Is it a separate component? You can not draw on the same surface as you have noted. You could try overlay a transparent window on which you draw. You may need to define opacity as 1, not to be completely transparent.

Comment: Thanks Tom. MFP(Media Foundation Platform) is a Microsoft Audio and Video stream API and has in the SDK. Also has headers for C++. Transparent pattern makes all shape transparent. Actually i thinking create shape with Hwnd. But how make line with hwnd?.